# Connection between Infinite continued fractions, elliptic integrals and AGM

Tags: special-functions, continued-fractions, transcendental-number-theory, experimental-mathematics, elliptic-integrals

It is known that at $x=1$, the following continued fraction represents $\frac{4}{\pi}$ and can be approximated rapidly using Gauss' Arithmetic Geometric mean.
$$C(x) = x +  \frac{1^{2}}{2x + \frac{3^{2}}{2x  + \frac{5^{2}}{2x + \frac{7^{2}}{2x + \cdots}}}}$$

Are there any other $x$ that $C(x)$ can be approximated through AGM quickly?
Is there any connection to elliptic integrals?

Comment: Mathworld says that $C(1) = 4/\pi$, not $\pi$.  

Comment: I meant represents in a crude way. I can correct it.

Comment: Okay, sorry to jump on you like that.  It is a good question.

Comment: The AGM doesn't make any use of that continued fraction for $4/\pi$, does it? So there's no reason to think there's any connection between AGM and $C(x)$, right?

Comment: $C(4n-3),~n\in\mathbb{N}$ is a rational multiple of $1/\pi$.

Comment: Because $C(x)$ is a ratio of Gamma functions.

Comment: see page 140 in Ramanujan's Notebooks, Part 2

Comment: @Nemo page 145 corollary 1.

Comment: @Nemo yeah it does not still help to find if there is an AGM

Comment: There might not be any relation to AGM. Why do you need AGM for this continued fraction?

Comment: @Nemo I believe $x=1$ cannot be an isolated case. Makes no sense.

Comment: @Turbo Cannot be isolated case, because no two functions ever attain the same value at some point? :)

Answer (score 5):

This is not an answer.

As was noted in the comments, the function $C(x)$ can be expressed in terms of the Gamma function, see Corollary 1 on page 145 in [Ramanujan's Notebook II](http://www.plouffe.fr/simon/math/Ramanujan's%20Notebooks%20II.pdf) which attributes this result to G. Bauer: Von einem Kettenbruche Euler's und einem Theorem von Wallis, Abh. Bayer. Akad. Wiss. 11(1872), 96 - 116 and to the first Ramanujan letter to Hardy.

$$
C(x) = \frac{\Gamma^2(\frac{x+1}{4})}{\Gamma^2(\frac{x+3}{4})}
$$

The AGM function can be expressed in terms of complete elliptic integral of the first kind, as is noted on the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean#Properties) page, which is given by [Gauss hypergeometric function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function)  ${}_2F_1(-\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}; 1; k^2)$ whereas the function $C(x)$ is [given by](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function#Special_values_at_z.C2.A0.3D.C2.A01) ${}_2F_1(-\frac{1}{2}, -\frac{1}{2};x,1)$.

There is certainly more to the story, see [related question on math.stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/170409/27752) and equation (99) at [MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GammaFunction.html).

The explicit relation connecting Gamma values at certain rational points and elliptic integral can be found e.g. in the article of [Borwein and Zucker](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/31423149_Fast_evaluation_of_the_gamma_function_for_small_rational_fractions_using_complete_elliptic_integrals_of_the_first_kind), book [Pi and the AGM by Borwein, Borwein](http://plouffe.fr/simon/math/Borwein%20-%20Pi%20and%20the%20AGM%20(Wiley,%201987).pdf) and a more recent article by [Vidunas](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0403510).

Comment: Note that the reference you cite attributes this corollary to Bauer 1872.

Comment: @VitTucek thank you. do you know how fast $(99)$ converges? is it as fast as AGM?

Comment: @Turbo My understanding is that it also converges quadratically.