# On existence of rapid Arithmetic geometric procedure?

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, algebraic-number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, continued-fractions, transcendental-number-theory

We know that $\pi$ can be computed by Arithmetic Geometric mean using Gauss-Legendre procedure which does provide fastest convergence rate as well with a guarantee of $2^n$ bits of $\pi$ at $n$th iteration.

This leads to the question what classes of continued fractions can be given as Arithmetic geometric procedure?

**1.** Does $C(x) = x +  \frac{1^{2}}{2x + \frac{3^{2}}{2x  + \frac{5^{2}}{2x + \frac{7^{2}}{2x + \cdots}}}}$ have a [rapid Arithmetic geometric procedure](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/117021/connection-between-infinite-continued-fractions-and-agm) at $x\in\Bbb Z_{\neq1}$ (note $C(1)=\frac{4}{\pi}$)?

**2.** Which algebraic numbers that have continued fraction expansion, admit rapid Arithmetic geometric procedure?

**3.** Since $\pi$ has rapid Arithmetic geometric procedure we have $\zeta(2n)$ having rapid Arithmetic geometric procedure. Does $\zeta(2n+1)$ admit rapid Arithmetic geometric procedure?

**4.** Supposing the fastest approximation for a number is through a rapid Arithmetic geometric procedure, is that number transcendental? Is there any connection to transcendentality through existence of rapid Arithmetic geometric procedure?

Comment: With regard to 2., for all algebraic numbers, Newton iteration has even lower computational complexity than AGM (faster by a $\log(n)$ factor). I don't know about AGM iteration for $\zeta(2n+1)$, but there are other algorithms that are almost as fast (slower by a $\log^c(n)$ factor).

Comment: @FredrikJohansson So could you elaborate the AGM technique for algebraic numbers?

Comment: I don't believe this is related to numerical analysis.

Comment: @FredrikJohansson what is the AGM technique for algebraic numbers?

Comment: @Turbo I meant that Newton iteration for computing algebraic numbers is faster than AGM iteration itself, regardless of whether the AGM can be used to compute algebraic numbers.